# How to get a total of recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000

I want to get the max(date) of total for each id.

```
ID Date Total

01 02/01/2012 500
01 01/02/2012 1000
01 02/03/2012 350
02 17/01/2012 250
02 15/02/2012 150
03 01/12/2011 225
...
...
```

I want to get max(date) of total for each id.

Tried Query

```
Select id, total from table1 where date > max(date) group by id, total
```

Getting error message as

"An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Expected Output

```
ID Date Total

01 02/03/2012 350
02 15/02/2012 150
03 01/12/2011 225
...
...
```

How to do this.

Need Query Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select id, date, total 
from table1 t
where date = (select max(date) from table1 where id = t.id
group by id)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
select *
from total t inner join
    (   select id, max(date) as date
        from total
        group by id ) m on t.id = m.id and t.date = m.date
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will work

```
select * from dbo.Table t1
where Date >= (select max(Date) from dbo.Table t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID)
```